# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, post, syntax

Очень прошу помогите новичку разобраться, пожалуйста.

На сайте имеется форма обратной связи, посылающая post средствами ajax. Суть в том, что форма отправляется, получатель письмо получает, но почему-то срабатывает параметр error у ajax.

В консоли ошибка синтаксиса SyntaxError (скрин прилагаю).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('.call_block button').on('click', function() {
  var data = $('.call_form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'callback.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('.call_block button').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function(data) {
      $('.call_block button').button('reset');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('.call_form input.error').removeClass('error');
      $('.call_form .error_span').remove();
      if (data.status == 0) {
        $.each(data.html, function(index, value) {
          $('[name=\"' + index + '\"]').addClass('error');
          $('[name=\"' + index + '\"]').after(value);
        });
      } else {
        $('.call_form').empty();
        $('.call_form').append(data.html);
        $('.call_form').append(data.botton);
      }
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
      $('body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Ошибка при отправки формы <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: в ответе сервера приходит html вместо json

Comment: подскажите, где поправить?

Comment: на сервере. Посмотри что именно тебе в ответ приходит

Comment: вот что пришло в response, файла callback.php: {"status":1,"html":"<p class=\"succes_p\">\u0421\u043f\u0430\u0441\u0438\u0431\u043e. \u0412 \u0441\u0430\u043c\u043e\u0435 \u0431\u043b\u0438\u0436\u0430\u0439\u0448\u0435\u0435 \u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f \u043c\u044b \u0432\u0430\u043c \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0437\u0432\u043e\u043d\u0438\u043c.<\/p>","botton":"<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"$('.call_form').hide('slow');$('body').removeClass('background');\" class=\"btn btn-block foot_close\">\u0417\u0430\u043a\u0440\u044b\u0442\u044c \u043e\u043a\u043d\u043e<\/button>"}

Comment: Выслал не совсем то, что нужно?

Comment: Да, покажи в браузере именно ответ.

Comment: Поймите пож, я абсолютный новичок в web, могу иногда переспрашивать, или не те ответы давать. Когда вы говорили о сервере, вы имели ввиду php файл callback? В браузере: network - callback.php - response?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106987/discussion-between-grundy-and-rabbit).

Comment: Привет. Решение с пробелами не помогло :-(